# How to take mean on groups

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the below database.

[image]

And I want the above data to look like this. Please help. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be:

```
df.groupby(['origin','model_year']).mean()
```

Comment: A minimum of 15 reputation points is needed before a user is eligible for voting up, which is clearly not the case here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges